# How to get reference to eclipse actions in the toolbar and menu and toggle its enabled/disabled state?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have contributed actions using `ui.actionSets` to my rcp app. Based on state change in the app I need to be able to get a reference to a specific action and either enable or disable its state. I know in the extension point you can set initial value but I need to be able to do this in runtime and can find any references in `WorkbenchUI`. Any help would be appreciated. - Duncan

Comment: If you can switch to using commands, they support this: http://www.robertwloch.net/2011/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-property-testers-with-command-core-expressions/

Comment: I don't know why but I've had such a hard time going with a framework I know which are actionSets to commands. I should Goolge is that a pretty straight forward framework?

Comment: About as complex as actions, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, was actually pretty easy. There are three extension points and you can have multiple handlers so that is a nice seperation from command and handler. Thanks for the comment.